# Matching array contents to pre-entered data

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array, the contents of which are a subset of a list of names that come from a checkbox question in a google form.  I need to email the people whose names are in the array, I suppose from a hard coded list (multi-dim array?).  I cannot figure out how to perform the search/comparisons/whatever.  Apparently I am supposes to use an object literal as in the code below:

```
var formNames = ["Name One", "Name Three"];  // one possibility for example

var objectMatchingNamesToEmails{
   "Name One":"nameone@work.com",
   "Name Two":"nametwo@work.com",
   "Name Three":"namethree@work.com",
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of the array of name, and the variable name that you are using for the array with the names in it.  You could use a `for` loop maybe, and loop through the array, look up the email, and at the same time build a new array of the looked up emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the array:

```
var arrayOfEmails,arrayOfNames,L,thisEmail,thisName;

arrayOfNames = ["NameOne","NameTwo"];

arrayOfEmails = [];
L = arrayOfNames.length;//The number of names in the array

for (var i = 0;i<L;i++) {
  thisName = arrayOfNames[i];
  thisEmail = objectMatchingNamesToEmails[thisName];
  arrayOfEmails.push(thisEmail);
};
```

Create an object literal:

```
var objectMatchingNamesToEmails;

objectMatchingNamesToEmails = {
  "NameOne":"exampleOne@gmail.com",
  "NameTwo":"exampleTwo@gmail.com",
  "NameThree":"exampleThree@gmail.com",
};
```

Then after you get the name, the code can look up the correct email:

```
var userName,userEmail;

userName = code here to get user name;

userEmail = objectMatchingNamesToEmails[userName];

MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail,subject,body);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! So an object literal can hold my entire list of name and email pairs. I suppose this is somehow superior to a multi-dim array for my purposes? I'm not understanding the lookup section yet. Please see the code in my edited question above.

Comment: To get a value out of an array, the index number must be known.  For data that is always ordered the same, it works fine, like rows that must always be in the same order.  To get a value out of an object, you can use the key name.  If the key name is not always the same, use bracket notation:  `var lookedUpValue = objectName[keyName]`  With bracket notation, the key name can be a variable with a changing value.

Comment: Thank you.  Just finished editing,  please take a look if you would be so kind.

Comment: I wrote a program based on your advice and it works!  Thanks a ton!  I'm not quite sure how these two lines function... could you elucidate for me?

`thisName = arrayOfNames[i];
  thisEmail = objectMatchingNamesToEmails[thisName];`

Comment: The letter `i` in this case is a variable that is a counter.  The counter begins at 0 and is incremented by 1 on every iteration of the loop.  An array is "zero indexed", meaning that the first element in the array has an index of zero.  The counter `i` is used to get a different value out of the array on every loop.  Enter a `Logger.log(i)` statement inside of the loop, run the code, and then in the "View" menu choose "Logs".  You will see a list of numbers printed to the log.  If this answered or helped answer your question, you can click the green check-mark to answer it as correct.

Comment: Nevermind... after researching javascript objects I get it now... the names are properties, and the emails are property values, and you are just calling values by name!  I now have a fully working script that I completely understand!  Thank you!!!  If I still need to clean things up to make it clear for others, please tell me what to change.  EDIT:  lol, we cross posted :)

Comment: Also, there may be an error in your code.  I could not get values to push to a var until I declared it an array by `var array=[];`